# Run time instance creation of sub classes in template design pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I am creating an application which has three algorithms with some common piece of code . Hence i decided to go with Template Design Pattern. I need to decide the algorithm to be called at runtime like below

```
switch(filetype){
case "test":
BaseClass b = new SubClass1();
b.convert();

case "test2":
BaseClass b = new SubClass12();
b.convert();
}
```

i want to avoid the  switch case while instance creation during run time and want to use Dependency injection to achieve the same. Could you suggest any pattern to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have these classes:

```
public interface IDependency{ }
public class DependencyOne : IDependency { }
public class DependencyTwo : IDependency { }
```

If you just want to remove switch case then your can use dictionary like this:

```
public static class DependencyFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<string, IDependency> _dependencies = new Dictionary<string, IDependency>
    {
        {"DependencyOne",new DependencyOne()},
        {"DependencyTwo",new DependencyTwo()},
    };

    public static IDependency GetDependency(string input)
    {
        return _dependencies[input];
    }
}
```

But if you want to use dependency injection then you should register your dependencies in IOC container:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IDependency, DependencyOne>();
        services.AddScoped<IDependency, DependencyTwo>();
    }
```

And resolve your dependency in a factory like this:

```
public class DependencyFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IDependency> _dependencies;

    public DependencyFactory(IEnumerable<IDependency> dependencies)
    {
        _dependencies = dependencies;
    }

    public IDependency GetDependency(string input)
    {
        return _dependencies.FirstOrDefault(dependency => dependency.GetType().Name == input);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i resolve the dependencies. Could you provide an example

Comment: Where?  In Dependency Factory ?

Comment: Yes  using factory

Comment: You can create an interface for your factory and inject your factory in every classes you want.